# update object using nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

JSON structure,

```
[
{'col 1':'false','col 2':'false','col 3':'false'},
{'col 1':'false','col 2':'false','col 3':'false'},
{'col 1':'false','col 2':'false','col 3':'false'},
{'col 1':'false','col 2':'false','col 3':'false'}
]
```

Please note the **key have space** in it. 
In controller i'm changing it to a scope object as,

```
$scope.myArr = angular.fromJson(jsonStringAsAbove);
```

My html code,

```
<div class='row' data-ng-repeat='i in myArr'>
    <table class='col-xs-12' style='overflow:auto;border:1px solid black;' >
       <tr>
          <td style='width:100px;' data-ng-repeat='o in i'>
             <input type='checkbox' data-ng-model='o' />
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

But, if I select the `check box`, the `myArr` is not changed properly. I suspect the `data-ng-model` which I'm binding to the `input` element is not proper. How can I bind the `input` element so that the original array will be updated to `true` or `false` based on the `check box` selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets' start by rewriting the code by giving proper names instead of i and o:

```
<div class='row' data-ng-repeat='row in myArr'>
    <table class='col-xs-12' style='overflow:auto;border:1px solid black;' >
       <tr>
          <td style='width:100px;' data-ng-repeat='column in row'>
             <input type='checkbox' data-ng-model='column' />
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This might look useless, but it makes things much easier to read, understand and maintain for everyone, including you.

Now let's look at the problems:

```
`data-ng-repeat='column in row'`
```

you can't iterate on `row` like that. `row` is an object with 3 fields, not an array.

The correct way to iterate over entries of an object is

```
`data-ng-repeat="(columnName, columnValue) in row`
```

Now you want the checkbox to be bound to the field of `row` that has the current column name, so the input should be

```
<input type='checkbox' data-ng-model='row[columnName]' />
```

Note, however, that the model of a checkbox is supposed to be a boolean, and not a string as your objects contain. The array should be defined as

```
[
    {'col 1': false, 'col 2': false, 'col 3': false},
    {'col 1': false, 'col 2': false, 'col 3': false},
    {'col 1': false, 'col 2': false, 'col 3': false},
    {'col 1': false, 'col 2': false, 'col 3': false}
]
```

Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9PA1sG5FiicY9Xl2toe1?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. Wasted 4 hours for a simple mistake. You have mentioned that the `array` should be defined with `boolean` instead of `string`. But when you use `angular.fromJson` it doesn't convert `string` to `boolean` automatically. should i have to iterate and convert it manually then?

Comment: You should fix the code that generates this JSON incorrectly. Why store a boolean as a string?